Facebook meta developer blocked ngrok? Error Message "URL Blocked"
I have developed a Meta app and I am encountering an error after successful authentication. During the callback got this type of error that they have blocked my url.

I have not engaged in any illegal activities. Despite trying different devices and URLs, I still receive the same error:

It seems that Meta is blocking URLs from ngrok and other similar platforms. I am unsure how to resolve this issue.
Has anyone faced a similar problem or have any suggestions on how to proceed? Are there any specific precautions or configurations I should be aware of to avoid this issue?

If they blocked these services in general, because too many people using them did malicious stuff, then there is little you can do about that.

I have tried using PageKite as a substitute for ngrok, and it is not blocked by the Facebook Meta app.
You can also use another substitute of ngrok, because for unblock the domain takes much time.
Some other alternatives include Serveo, LocalTunnel, and Teleconsole.

i find the answer to my problem in this topic. Ngrok webhooks not getting verified in Meta webhook's callbackurl
It works fine for me as webhook to Facebook Wpp API
